# Custom Action for specific list view - SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

How can I target custom ribbon action menus for specific list views? I want to be displayed in the default view of the list but to be hidden in the other views.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is old, yet unanswered , I am responding to it.
Create an empty Sharepoint Project in VS2010 , add an `Elements.xml` file in the project and past following XML in it.

```
    <CustomAction Id="MyCustomButton" Sequence="999"
                      GroupId="Manage"
                      Location="CommandUI.Ribbon" // Location to display button
                      RegistrationId="101" // on every list, for  a specific list or library put the GUID of list here e.g. RegistrationId="{GUID_OF_LIST}"
                      RegistrationType="List"
                      Rights="ManageWebs"
                      Title="Custom Document Library Button">
            <CommandUIExtension>
                <CommandUIDefinitions>
                    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.Manage.Controls._children">
                        <Button Id="Ribbon.Documents.Manage.Controls.CustomButton" TemplateAlias="o1"
                                ToolTipDescription="Creates a server side action."
                                ToolTipTitle="SSRibbon" LabelText="SS Action"
                                Image32by32="/_layouts/images/ContractClaims/newproject.jpg"
                                Image16by16="/_layouts/images/ContractClaims/newproject.jpg" Alt="New Project"
                                Command="{3E04C0C1-12DD-449E-905F-7E88EB9E22B1}"
                                Sequence="20"/>
                    </CommandUIDefinition>
                </CommandUIDefinitions>
                <CommandUIHandlers>
                    <CommandUIHandler Command="{3E04C0C1-12DD-449E-905F-7E88EB9E22B1}"

                                     CommandAction="javascript:alert ('Hello World' ) ;" />
                </CommandUIHandlers>
            </CommandUIExtension>
        </CustomAction>
```

The several locations to display the button can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb802730.aspx).For more on the top you can google respective XML elements.

Comment: I've mentioned that I want to show the custom action in the default list view and not in the other list views the list has.

Comment: @NLV, you can use `Location=CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView` in the `CustomAction` tag for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **EnabledScript** parameter in [CommandUIHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff458385.aspx), where you can put javascript code and check if specific page/list/view is loaded.

[link to similar answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/130987/14566)

Example:

```
<CommandUIHandler 
  Command="Ribbon.ListItem.CustomGroup.Controls.BtnSayHello.Command"
  CommandAction="javascript:alert('Hello');"
  EnabledScript="javascript:
    function isEnable(){
      if(location.href.indexOf('AllItems.aspx') > 0){
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
    isEnable();"
/>
```